# Generate picture and save it on server php

Tags: php, generated-code

How to generate a picture of graph of the results of voting and how to save the image in my server host, to continue to use it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Generating Grapsh etc.** 
You can use [link](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) PHPExcel
and there is a possibility to save all generated files 
eg: `$objWriter->save('namee.xls');` check detail from the documentation

**Saving without using PHPexcel etc.** 
if you have a graph or smth else and you want to save it on your server side 
to save something you can use

```
            $fp = fopen($name, "w");
            fwrite($fp, $content); // this line saves 
            fclose($fp);
```

Comment: I want generate picture with grapph, not excel

Comment: okay I got it , but how are you going to generate a graph without using any library PHPExcel was an example to do this. Via that library you do not have to export ONLY Excel files. You can generate Excel Chart or Graph Style images and save as JPG , PNG etc. if you have an idea for generating image in a different way write it then I will try to help in detail